# MySQL first value interpreted as columnname

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Using JDBC, I'm trying to execute the following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO meta (title, hlcount, textcount, imgcount, linkcount) VALUES (SomeString,6,4794,1,76)
```

But this returns the errormessage

> Unknown column 'SomeString' in 'field list'

So it seems the first of the values is being interpreted as a column, how's that?

Already checked the table structure, maybe I just tunneled on this one but I just can't seem to find the cause for this problem.

Comment: Try "SomeString" instead of SomeString.

Comment: try 'someString' instead

Comment: did you add quotes to your string?

Comment: String in quotes variables without quotes :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So it seems the first of the values is being interpreted as a column, how's that?

Because you've got it just as `SomeString`, instead of as a text *value* such as `'SomeString'`. That's just how SQL works - and it's how normal code works too, really. If you had:

```
String foo = bar;
```

you would expect that to be trying to copy the value of a variable called `bar`, wouldn't you? If you meant a string of three characters, b, a, r, you'd use:

```
String foo = "bar";
```

It's just the same in SQL.

However, assuming this SQL is being built up from real values, you should be using a `PreparedStatement` with parameters anyway:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO meta (title, hlcount, textcount, imgcount, linkcount)"
             + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, "SomeString");
pst.setInt(2, 6);
// etc
```

That way you'll avoid SQL injection attacks and string conversion problems (e.g. for dates). It also keeps your SQL cleaner, separating the code from the data.

Answer (score 2):

String should be within single quotes('').

```
INSERT INTO meta (title, hlcount, textcount, imgcount, linkcount) VALUES ('SomeString',6,4794,1,76)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around SomeString.

```
INSERT INTO meta 
  (title, hlcount, textcount, imgcount, linkcount) 
VALUES ('SomeString',6,4794,1,76)
```

This'll coerce the engine into treating it as a string literal.  Otherwise, it'll assume that it is something that can be resolved via a column name.

Answer (score 1):

when ever you are inserting date or string values you have to enclose with

either '' (single quotes ) [always use this]

or " "( back tick character ) [not always]

INSERT INTO meta (title, hlcount, textcount, imgcount, linkcount) VALUES ('SomeString',6,4794,1,76)

or

INSERT INTO meta (title, hlcount, textcount, imgcount, linkcount) VALUES ("SomeString",6,4794,1,76)

Answer (score 1):

you should use single quotes 'Somestring'.

```
 INSERT INTO meta (title, hlcount, textcount, imgcount, linkcount) VALUES  ('SomeString',6,4794,1,76)
```

because SomeString denotes the text value to be inserted in the title column and text should always be surrounded with single quotes.